# Odoo one2many field creation and assign to self.variable

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

```
for fee_line in fee_criteria.fee_line_ids:
        fee_data = {
                       'name' : fee_line.name,
                       'amount' : int(fee_line.amount),
                       'type' : fee_line.type,
                       'fee_pay_type' : fee_line.fee_pay_type.id,
                       'reg_form_id':self.id,
                       'sequence': fee_line.sequence,
                    }
        fee_lst.append((0,0,fee_data))
        self.student_fee_line = fee_lst
```

This is out for below code :

output:-

```
fees.line(<openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e0130110>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e0130390>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00d6850>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00d6610>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00d63d0>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00d6190>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00d6d90>, <openerp.models.NewId object at 0x7f86e00dc050>)
```

I am not getting Ids so what i do.

Comment: I think you are doing this in a compute field or onchange and doing this is risky you should override the write method. It's beyter tp explain what you want to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

In new ids context all work is done in the cache. And after that check all function and ids in python file, and creating a record in a model with computed fields, the records of the recordset will be in memory only. At that time the id of the record will be a dummy ids of type `openerp.models.NewId`.

```
if isinstance(current_record.id, models.NewId):
    # do your stuff
```

This is a `@siva.singh` post at [How to use New ids in Odoo ?](http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-use-New-ids-in-Odoo-/12355/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the `'reg_form_id':self.id,` key and value from the vals as you already are passing the list of dict to o2m field.